# Error 948 :Visual Studio 2012 with SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a computer that working as server and client machine. I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 and Visual Studio 2012 in it.

Using SQL server management studio I generated a DB then I created few table in that DB , then I insert data into it.

Then I deattached that DB using Server Management studio . Then I move that DB into my project "App_Data" folder.Then using "server explorer" & T_SQL pane functions of Visual Studio 2012 I did few changes of that DB .

Since I want to do massive changes , I close that DB connection with the project. I move that DB into  SQL server default Database Location which is

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA"

then I try to attach that DB using server management studio ,  I'm getting

> "Error 948"
>
> Cannot be opened because it is version 706. This server supports
>   version 661 and earlier

How to overcome this error ? your ideas/suggestions highly appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, you can't attach a DB file from a SQL Server 2012 to an instance which is running SQL Server 2008 R2.

Version 661 is a SQL Server 2008 R2 DB file and version 706 is a SQL Server 2012 DB file. More information: [How to determine version of Local Sql Instance and your database](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pranav_rastogi/archive/2012/02/20/mapping-sql-mdf-file-versions-to-sql-product-versions.aspx)

You will therefore need to update your SQL Server instance, e.g. by upgrading to SQL Server 2012

I would also recommend you patch to the newest released build of SQL Server 2012. Check here for the newest version numbers for the different SQL Server versions: [Microsoft SQL Server Version List](http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com)

Answer (score 0):

its a version comparability issue.

Initially you created in sqlserver 2008 R2 that version would be 661 and when you moved to VS2012 it was updated to 706, and when you tried to go back to SQl server 2008 R2 again this 706 version is not being downgraded to 661, obviously it can't be done.

one simple solution without any changes to your server setup, use Generate Script feature that should help you.